# csv.foreach stuck, not calling the block

Tags: ruby, csv, lambda

I am trying to write a CSV "fixer".
Unfortunately It seems that the csv.foreach instruction is not calling the lambda I have created. The CPU is used at 100%. Just wondering what ruby is doing in the meantime...

Any ideas why my code is wrong?

```
  1 require "csv"
  2 
  3 ARGV.empty? do
  4     print "usage: fixcsv.rb <filename>"
  5     exit
  6 end
  7 
  8 filename_orig = Dir.pwd + "/" + ARGV[0]
  9 filename_dest = filename_orig.sub(/csv$/,"tmp.csv")
 10 topic = filename_orig.sub(/_entries.csv$/,"").sub(/.*\//,"")
 11 
 12 puts "topic:" + topic
 13 
 14 writer = CSV.open(filename_dest,"w",:col_sep=>";")
 15 #i=0
 16 cycler = lambda do |row|
 17     #i = i + 1
 18     #puts "row number:" + i.to_str
 19     #row[17] = topic
 20     puts "foo"
 21     writer << row
 22 end
 23 
 24 begin
 25     CSV.foreach(filename_orig,:col_sep=>",",&cycler)
 26 rescue
 27     puts "exception:" + $!.message
 28     exit
 29 else
 30     writer.close
 31 end
```

Here is the stack trace produced when I Ctrl-C it:

stab@ubuntu:~/wok$ ruby addtopic.rb civilpoliticalrights_entries.csv

```
topic:civilpoliticalrights
^C/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:914:in `buf_size': Interrupt
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:825:in `[]'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:354:in `parse_body'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:227:in `parse_row'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:637:in `get_row'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:556:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:531:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:311:in `open_reader'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/csv.rb:94:in `foreach'
    from addtopic.rb:25
```

EDIT: Ruby version is:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
```

Comment: We are going to need to know what version of Ruby you are on in order to give a good answer, as you are using API elements that are drastically different between csv in 1.8.7 and csv in 1.9.x. It's an unfortunate situation. (I suppose 1.9 may take the old API but if you are on 1.8.7 I would prefer to just concentrate on that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program worked fine for me in Ruby 1.9.

I have a few observations:

- If your input pathname does not end in `csv`, then the input and output file names will be the same. This could easily produce an infinite loop.
- You are definitely using the 1.9 flavor of csv. If this program needs to run on 1.8.7 it would need to have patches from the snippet below...

Mods for 1.8.7:

```
writer = CSV.open(filename_dest, "w", ?;)
#i=0
cycler = lambda do |row|
  #i = i + 1
  #puts "row number:" + i.to_str
  #row[17] = topic
  writer << row
end

begin
  CSV.open filename_orig, 'r', ?,, &cycler
```

The main problem with 1.8.7 csv is that the interfaces to `CSV.open` and `CSV.foreach` do not take Hash options. Worse, they are expecting numeric code points, a feature of Ruby that apparently didn't work out and was withdrawn in 1.9.